# How to get non grouped-by columns in SQL statement (similar to in MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

In MySQL, I can do the following query:

```
select first_name from `table` group by age
```

[image]

However, if I do something similar in BigQuery, I get the following error:

> SELECT list expression references column first_name which is neither grouped nor aggregated

How would we write the equivalent mysql aggregation query in BigQuery?

Comment: Actually, the newest version of MySQL has that disabled by default, as such queries are generally considered bad. That query gives you an effectively random selection of (first_name, last_name) from each age.

Comment: @Uueerdo -- that's fine. That's what I want actually.

Comment: what behavior do you expect from such query?

Comment: @Pedro see screenshot above, please.

Comment: Is that screenshot what you want, or what you're getting?

Comment: @lurker -- that's what I want (what I currently get in mysql). I'm trying to convert that type of query into BigQuery -- not that exact query, but basically being able to show something like `select *` whenever I do an aggregation.

Comment: @lurker Gordon's answer is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and as simple as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ANY_VALUE(first_name) first_name
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY age
```

As you can see you were missing just aggregation function - it can be any - MAX, MIN, etc. I've chosen ANY_VALUE as an example

You can test, play with above using some simplified dummy data like in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Thomas' first_name, 25 age UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mike', 25 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Thomas', 30 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mark', 40
)
SELECT ANY_VALUE(first_name) first_name
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY age
```

with result

```
Row first_name   
1   Thomas   
2   Thomas   
3   Mark
```

Comment: thanks, this is actually exactly what I was looking to find out.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put all the selected column in `group by` also

```
 select first_name, last_name from 
`table` group by age,first_name, last_name
```

btw before 8.0 version of mysql it was allow but from 8.0 it is not allow

but in you query there is no aggregate function so you can use distinct rather than group by

```
select distinct first_name, last_name from 
    `table`
```

Comment: thanks, please see updated question where using `distinct` wouldn't work.

Comment: use group by first_name and age

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, you should be using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by age order by age) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This works in MySQL 8+ as well.

Comment: finally, thank you very much, this is what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, could you please explain why you need to order by `age` and get the `row_number()` ?

Comment: @DavidL . . . The standard requires `order by` for `row_number()`.  Although BigQuery doesn't, I tend to include `order by` whenever I use the function.