# Does GROUP BY x = DISTINCT (all columns - x)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Supposing I have ten fields in a sql table, is doing `GROUP BY field1` always the same as doing `SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, ...`. Why or why not? I've tested this out a bit and it seems to be valid in what I've tried but I'm looking for a bit of a more rigorous explanation.

Comment: No.  I am surprised that you would think that these are ever the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff right -- after some more testing it seems they are (usually) wildly different. Is there any way to convert a `group by` clause into doing a `distinct` ? For more details on what I'm trying to accomplish, here's the issue I'm running into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772283/how-to-get-non-grouped-by-columns-in-sql-statement-similar-to-in-mysql

Comment: The question in that link doesn't really make it much clearer what you're trying to do. Why do you need to "convert" a GROUP BY to a DISTINCT? You need to (a) share your table schema, (b) provide a small example data set, (c) explain what results you want your query to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Column01,
  Column02,
  Column03,
  Column04
FROM
  TableA
```

Is functionally the same as writing:

```
SELECT 
  Column01,
  Column02,
  Column03,
  Column04
FROM
  TableA
GROUP BY 
  Column01,
  Column02,
  Column03,
  Column04
```

To be more specific, `DISTINCT` is the same as doing a `GROUP BY` on all of the columns in the `SELECT` list. If you want a `GROUP BY` that will give you the same results as a `DISTINCT`, just include all of your columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Older versions of MySQL allowed for relaxed (some might say sloppy) implementation of `GROUP BY`, where gaps in coding were filled in with underlying assumptions, which may or may not have been valid in any given case, and the actual functionality was effectively masked from the user. Such as the case in [the question you linked to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772283/how-to-get-non-grouped-by-columns-in-sql-statement-similar-to-in-mysql)

If you're looking for anything more specific to your actual issue, you'll need to edit your question to include, well, more specificity.